# Get Node_Modules without Install

Tags: node.js, npm, teamcity, node-modules

what i want to try is that i can run my VueJS Project without npm install.
What i tried that i include my node_modules but on the Build Server it failed with the message, that some Modules are Missing. It only work when i use the command `npm install` in.

I try to build it in Teamcity.

Is there a way to like zip or pack the node_modules and tell webpack this zip or whatever are the Node_modules to build.

I run no Teamcity `npm run build` and need only the outcoming dist folder.

I hope you guys know my little issue and hope that you guys can help me.

Kind Regards,
Thomas M.

Comment: i think you should not pack node_modules and supply it. insted `npm install` .

Comment: yeah thats what i think. But im building no a Buildserver and we want to build as fast as it can go. The npm install take about 1 - 1.30 Minutes. And our Firewall (Sophos) had yesterday no connection to the npm registry. So i try to somehow include the node_modules so i wont need to use `npm install`. So i want only to use `npm run build`.

Comment: then most probably you should not add the `npm_modules ` folder in `.gitignore` .
in that case, you install all dependency in local and ship it with the code in the server & it will automatically take it and to run `npm run build` you can edit the `build` command in `package.json ` accordingly. you can remove the `npm install ` part from there.
most probably i'm not able to catch the issue.

Comment: You should ask to your infrastructure team to whitelist any request to npm registry. Then, probably using [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/) your build will speed up. Last, but not least, you should instruct TeamCity to cache `node_modules` per branch, so you would be very fast.
committing or packing node_modules is that kind of ideas that will turn against you in future :)

Comment: You can try [npm ci](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ci)

Comment: @saikatchakrabortty do you mean remove `node_modules` from the `.gitignore`? If Yes then i already did this :) but if run afterwards If the node_modules are included it tells me that Modules are still missing. I watched inside the Node_Modules folder but inside there is this missing module.

Comment: @Hitmands so i would try maybe to run `npm install -g` to have it saved globally?

Comment: @GabrielBleu can you describe what npm ci actually does? Because in the Document it tells `can only install entire projects at a time: individual dependencies cannot be added with this command.`

Comment: @ThomasMeejumlong not at all. Just search on google how to cache in teamcity

Comment: This command is similar to npm-install, except it's meant to be used in automated environments such as test platforms, continuous integration, and deployment. It can be significantly faster than a regular npm install by skipping certain user-oriented features.

Comment: @GabrielBleu Okay then i might have a problem because it tells me ... `Did you mean one of these?
    c
    i

` npm@5.6.0 and on the build server it is npm  v3.10.10

Comment: @ThomasMeejumlong yes it's new, starting from [v5.7.0](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/171139955345/v570)

Comment: @GabrielBleu alright i give it a try then. I will update my question if succeed or i will write you back in this command section :) thank you